# Как сделать перегрузку оператора + методом класса?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define N 10

class Fraction
{

private:
    int chys,
        zn;
public:
    Fraction() : chys(0), zn(0) {}

    Fraction(int chysl, int znl) : chys(chysl), zn(znl) {}

    Fraction(const Fraction &obj) : chys(obj.chys), zn(obj.zn) {}

    int GetChys() { return chys; }
    int GetZn() { return zn; }
    void setFraction(int x, int y) { chys = x; zn = y; }

    int CommonZn(Fraction *obj)
    {
        int q = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; q != 1; i++)
        {
            if ((i % this->zn == 0) && (i % obj->zn == 0))
            {
                q = 1;
                this->chys *= (i / this->zn);
                obj->chys *= (i / obj->zn);
            }
        }
        this->zn = i - 1;
        obj->zn = i - 1;
        return i - 1;
    }

    int skor(int *chys, int *zn)
    {
        int i = 0, b = 0;
        if (*chys > *zn) { b = *chys; }
        else (b = *zn);
        for (i = b; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (*chys%i == 0 && *zn%i == 0)
            {
                *chys = *chys / i;
                *zn = *zn / i;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

    Fraction const& operator=(const Fraction &second)
    {
        chys = second.chys; zn = second.zn;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        Fraction second_common = obj;
        this->CommonZn(&second_common);
        return (this->chys == obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator >= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        Fraction second_common = obj;
        this->CommonZn(&second_common);
        return (this->chys >= obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator > (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        Fraction second_common = obj;
        this->CommonZn(&second_common);
        return (this->chys / this->zn > obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator < (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        Fraction second_common = obj;
        this->CommonZn(&second_common);
        return ((double)this->chys / this->zn < (double)obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator <= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        Fraction second_common = obj;
        this->CommonZn(&second_common);
        return (this->chys <= obj.chys);
    }

    friend Fraction operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second);
    friend Fraction operator -(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second);
    friend Fraction operator /(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second);
    friend Fraction operator *(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second);
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &in, Fraction &fraction);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr);

    ~Fraction() {}
};


Fraction operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    Fraction first_common = first, second_common = second;
    first_common.CommonZn(&second_common);
    return Fraction(first_common.GetChys() + second_common.GetChys(), first_common.GetZn());
}

Fraction operator -(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    Fraction first_common = first, second_common = second;
    first_common.CommonZn(&second_common);
    return Fraction(first_common.GetChys() - second_common.GetChys(), first_common.GetZn());
}

Fraction operator /(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    return Fraction(first.chys*second.zn, first.zn*second.chys);
}

Fraction operator *(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
{
    return Fraction(first.chys*second.chys, first.zn*second.zn);
}

istream &operator >> (istream &in, Fraction &fraction) 
{
    in >> fraction.chys;
    in.ignore(1);
    in >> fraction.zn;
    return in;
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr)
{
    out << fr.chys << "/" << fr.zn;
    return out;
}

void Sort(Fraction *FrArray[]);
//double avarage(Fraction FrArray[]);

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("color f0");
    system("cls");
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int chys1, zn1, chys2, zn2;


    Fraction *PtrFrArray[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        PtrFrArray[i] = new Fraction(1 + rand() % 10, 1 + rand() % 10);
        cout << *PtrFrArray[i] << endl;
    }

    Sort(PtrFrArray); 

    cout << endl << "Сортований масив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << *PtrFrArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    double avar = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        avar += (double) (*PtrFrArray[i]).GetChys() / (*PtrFrArray[i]).GetZn();
    }
    cout << "Середнє значення масиву = "  << avar/N << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete  PtrFrArray[i];
    }

    Fraction *A = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nПерший дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *A;
    Fraction *B = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nДругий дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *B;  
    Fraction *C = new Fraction(*A);
    cout << "Третій дріб " << endl;
    cin >> *C;
    if (*A < *C && *C < *B) cout << "A < C < B: " << "Успішне порівняння" << endl;
    else cout << "A < C < B: " << "Помилка" << endl;
    cout << "A + B + C = " << *A + *B + *C;


    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete C;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void Sort(Fraction *FrArray[])
{
    Fraction changer;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (*FrArray[i] > *FrArray[j])
            {
                changer = *FrArray[i];
                *FrArray[i] = *FrArray[j];
                *FrArray[j] = changer;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*double avarage(Fraction *FrArray[])
{
    double avar = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        avar = avar + (double)(*FrArray[i]).GetChys()/ (*FrArray[i]).GetZn();
    }
    return(avar/N);
}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Да примерно так же - просто роль `first` теперь у вас выполняет `*this`.

```
Fraction Fraction::operator +(const Fraction &second) const
{
    Fraction first_common = *this, second_common = second;
    first_common.CommonZn(&second_common);
    return Fraction(first_common.GetChys() + second_common.GetChys(), first_common.GetZn());
}
```

Но какой в этом глубокий смысл? это оператор `+=` имеет смысл как член класса определять.

Вот смотрите, если бы у вас был конструктор типа

```
Fraction(int chysl, int znl = 1) : chys(chysl), zn(znl) {}
```

то тогда присваивание

```
Fraction x, y;
...
y = 1 + x;
```

при свободном операторе сложения вполне имело бы смысл. А при операторе-члене класса первым слагаемым должен быть только объект этого самого класса - т.е.

```
y = Fraction(1) + x;
```